# Decoding error with urllib

Tags: python, encoding, urllib

I want to open a text file with accented characters (ç, ã, é, etc) from an url. This is the test code:

```
#coding:utf-8

import urllib

murl = urllib.urlopen('http://www.****.com.br/sampletext.txt')
print murl.geturl()
print murl.read()
```

It works well and prints everything just fine, but if I comment out this line...

`#print murl.geturl()`

...I get this error message (repeated 2 times)

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

Why does printing the url before printing out its content avoids that error?

Comment: This seems to be about sublime text, not python

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you have listed directory with file "python" in your $PATH (or %PATH% on windows) variable?